# O(1) removal of first element of an R list

Tags: r, list

Is there a way of removing the first element of an R list that is O(1) ?

I have tried several approaches including slicing and setting the first element of the list to NULL but all of my attempts seem to be O(n) presumably due to the list being copied.

Here is the test code I used

```
library(tictoc)
    k <- 15
    N <- Map(function(n) 100*2^n,0:k)
    T <- c()
    for(n in N)
    {
        l <- as.list(1:n)
        tic(quiet=TRUE)
        # uncomment just ONE of the following to assess complexity
            ## method 1 - set the first element to NULL
            # l[[1]] <- NULL
            ## method 2 - slice the list and reassign
            # l <- l[2:length(l)]
            ## method 3 - drop the first entry
            # l[-1]
        res <- toc(quiet=TRUE)
        t <- as.numeric(res$toc - res$tic)
        T <- c(T,t)
    }
    plot(N,T)
```

For example, using method 1 I get

[image]

Comment: Please specify how your list looks.

Comment: R should not copy a list when you delete an element with e.g `l[[1]]  <- NULL`. The pointer to the list itself will change, but the memory address of the items in the list will not. Similarly, even if you a copy some elements of a list with `lapply()` or `Filter()`, R won't make copies of the list items (unless you mutate them). A vector is different because it needs to be contiguous in memory. As @Friede asks, can you include some code creating and deleting elements of your object so we can see what the issue you're running into is?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Here is the code I use to assess the complexity of 3 different approaches

Comment: Once you migrate the code in the (not-an-)answer to your question, I can upvote as interesting. i don't know that there's an easy answer, tbh, but it's a fair question, it would be nice to find something less than `O(n)` if not `O(1)` itself. (In languages where more direct memory usage is afforded, this should be `O(1)` depending on the type of object; it's just not as direct in R, I suspect.)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to benchmark this? `l[-1]` should never be a performance bottleneck. Use `l[-1]`, you can't do better. The other list elements are not copied during this operation. What you see is the time needed to copy and modify the vector of pointers and possibly to call the garbage collector (if your list elements are large).

Here is proof that list elements are not copied:

```
l1 <- as.list(1:10) 
l2 <- l1[-1]
data.table::address(l1[[2]])
#[1] "000001fbabbdd3f0"
data.table::address(l2[[1]])
#[1] "000001fbabbdd3f0"
```

Comment: I don't disagree that this might not be the best "code optimization" effort, but the plot the OP provided suggests it is `O(n)`, which seems unnecessarily high to me. I'm curious, if nothing else. I did a similar benchmark on my own and came to the same deduction.

Comment: Hi. I am benchmarking this because I would like to use a deque like data structure that works efficiently. I understand that your example shows that the address of the data is the same. However, I am still uncertain as to why my benchmark code results suggests O(n) ? Have I made a mistake in the code somewhere ?

Comment: I have just re-read Roland's response and I think the suggestion is that the list is a vector of pointers to the objects being stored. Is this correct ? I can see how this might be a good way to get O(1) random access to an inhomogeneous collection of objects, but it does not make for a efficient (homogenous) deque. Is there a better choice of R data structure to get realise the efficient deque I require ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think big O notation is not very helpful here. Technically you can say it is O(n) as it scales linearly with the number of elements in the list. But as Roland's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78166989/12545041) says, R is copying the vector of pointers, so the actual amount of time should not be the bottleneck.

#### Some benchmarks

We can replicate each of the methods in your code, and also in each case force a deep copy for comparison.

```r
results <- bench::press(
    list_length = 10^(1:4),
    {
        l <- lapply(seq_len(list_length), \(x) sample(letters, x, replace = TRUE))
        bench::mark(
            min_iterations = 1,
            time_unit = "ms",
            max_iterations = 100,
            subset__standard = {
                l[2:length(l)]
            },
            subset__deep_copy = {
                rlang::duplicate(l[2:length(l)])
            },            
            neg_index__standard = {
                l[-1]
            },
            neg_index__deep_copy = {
                rlang::duplicate(l[-1])
            },            
            assign_null__standard = {
                l2 <- l
                l2[[1]] <- NULL
                l2
            },
            assign_null__deep_copy = {
                l2 <- rlang::duplicate(l)
                l2[[1]] <- NULL
                l2
            },
        )
    }
)
```

##### Output

Although the time increases, none of these methods take more than 0.4 milliseconds. Conversely, with the deep copy methods, they take hundreds of times as long:

[image]

Note that I've let the y-axis scale in the top and bottom facets differ as the time differences are so large. The numeric values are below, but ultimately I would not get too hung up on big O notation here. If you have lists so large that the time copying the pointers is an issue, any operations you are going to do on them will take much longer.

##### Output table

```
   method      type      list_length        min     median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
   <chr>       <chr>           <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1 subset      standard           10   0.00100    0.00170  231267.          0B     0      100     0
 2 subset      deep_copy          10   0.00220    0.00420  184366.          0B     0      100     0
 3 neg_index   standard           10   0.000500   0.000700 804504.          0B     0      100     0
 4 neg_index   deep_copy          10   0.00190    0.00250  176710.          0B     0      100     0
 5 assign_null standard           10   0.00100    0.00120  776399.          0B     0      100     0
 6 assign_null deep_copy          10   0.00250    0.00280  312208.          0B     0      100     0
 7 subset      standard          100   0.00140    0.00180  494067.      1.26KB     0      100     0
 8 subset      deep_copy         100   0.0168     0.0190    35372.     44.41KB     0      100     0
 9 neg_index   standard          100   0.00140    0.00190  317561.      2.14KB     0      100     0
10 neg_index   deep_copy         100   0.0145     0.0166    48181.     45.29KB     0      100     0
11 assign_null standard          100   0.00260    0.00290  325204.      1.65KB     0      100     0
12 assign_null deep_copy         100   0.0153     0.0169    51784.     43.98KB     0      100     0
13 subset      standard         1000   0.0111     0.0116    76063.      11.8KB     0      100     0
14 subset      deep_copy        1000   0.589      0.702      1391.      3.88MB     0      100     0
15 neg_index   standard         1000   0.0118     0.0128    51070.     19.72KB     0      100     0
16 neg_index   deep_copy        1000   0.614      0.724      1249.      3.89MB     0      100     0
17 assign_null standard         1000   0.0237     0.0247    30175.     15.71KB     0      100     0
18 assign_null deep_copy        1000   0.670      0.774      1054.      3.88MB     0      100     0
19 subset      standard        10000   0.144      0.192      5104.    117.27KB     0      100     0
20 subset      deep_copy       10000 277.       367.            2.73  382.15MB     0        2     0
21 neg_index   standard        10000   0.245      0.272      2625.     195.5KB     0      100     0
22 neg_index   deep_copy       10000  65.6       66.7          15.0   382.23MB     7.50     2     1
23 assign_null standard        10000   0.352      0.403      2363.    156.34KB     0      100     0
24 assign_null deep_copy       10000  65.4       72.9          13.7   382.12MB    20.6      2     3
```

#### Code to generate the plot

```r
results |>
    dplyr::mutate(expression = as.character(expression))  |>
    tidyr::separate_wider_delim(
        expression,
        "__",
        names = c("method", "type")
    )  |>
    ggplot(
        aes(x = list_length, y = median)
    ) +
    geom_point(aes(color = method, shape = type), size = 5) +
    facet_grid(rows = vars(type), cols = vars(method), scales = "free") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. I want to run a dynamic simulation with > 5000000 elements in a list with items being  randomly added and removed at the front/back of a list in a tight loop with many iterations. I think scalability (and hence big O) are still significant when scaling up the size of the simulation. A doubly linked list would work much better for me - is there anything along these lines that I could use ?

Comment: @grosed I see the problem. You could try [`container::deque()`](https://rpahl.github.io/container/reference/dequeS3.html) but when I tried it, it wasn't quicker than a list. You're going to struggle to do a tight loop in pure R. I would check out `Rcpp` or [`cpp11`](https://github.com/r-lib/cpp11), or if you know Rust, I like [`rextendr`](https://github.com/extendr/rextendr). If you write the loop in a compiled language it will be much quicker.

Comment: I have done a bench mark of a python deque which performs very nicely at scale and is O(1). Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @grosed glad you've found a way forward. If you're using python I'd check out [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/) for the JIT compiler. It's great you've found an O(1) solution but it still seems to me that the bottleneck is going to be the actual calculations you're performing.

Comment: The calculations are almost trivial and O(1). The value of interest is how the size of the data varies over time. Most of my work is focused on dynamic data sets used to process high velocity data. I think that R is more appropriate for static data. My next requirement is for the dynamic update of order statistics which suggests a self balancing order statistic tree working in conjunction with a deque. I guess that R does not have anything approximating the former ?